# Make an SQL query a drop down menu

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

I have two SQL queries that display different results from my database. I'm using these results as navigation links in my nav bar.
At the moment all the results display as a single line of text, I want to make each SQL query display as a drop down menu, with all the results from the query as an option in the drop down.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php

$q = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM Category";
$result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'], $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<a href='category.php?id=$row[0]'>$row[1]</a> ";
    //display product categories
}
mysqli_free_result($result); //free result

$q = "SELECT brand_id, brand_name FROM Brand";
$result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'], $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<a href='brand.php?id=$row[0]'>$row[1]</a> ";
    //display product Brands
}
?>
```

Comment: use select tag instead anchor.

Comment: they display as a single line of text cause you only wrap them in an <a> tag. so wrap each result set in a <ul>/list then use CSS to style it.

Comment: You're saving your db connection in a session? That's weird. Also the argument order in mysqli_query() is wrong: query first, connection second.

Answer (score 1):

use `select` `option`

```
echo "<select name='category'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
   echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[1]</option> ";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$q="SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM Category";
$result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);
$option1.="<select name='category'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
   $option1.="<option value='$row[0]'>$row[1]</option> ";
}
$option1.="</select>";
```

same for second
print this $option1 value in your view file

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="document.location.href='category.php?id='+this.value;">  
<?php   
    $result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)):?>
    <option value="<?=$row[0];?>"><?=$row[1];?></option>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry Chris. That was a typo.

Comment: `onchange` expexts javascript code, so don't prepend it with `javascript:`.