# php - Drop Down Executes Query On Post?

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

I've looked online and most drop down tutorials are for ratings e.g. matching the drop down value with a rating. I need to execute a query which corresponds to a number in the dropdown and the results to display once a user clicks submit, I don't want to use javascript. In my HTML :

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="genericForm">
<fieldset>
<p>Filter Rating</p>
<select name="value">
<option value="1">One Star</option>
<option value="2">Two Stars</option>
<option value="3">Three Stars</option>
<option value="4">Four Stars</option>
<option value="5">Five Stars</option>
</select>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"><br  />
</form>
```

The php :

```
<?php 
$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
if($_POST['value'] == '1') { 
    // query to get all 1 star ratings
    $query = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE genre='action' AND rating='1'"; 
} 
elseif($_POST['value'] == '2') { 
    // query to get all 2 star ratings
    $query = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE genre='action' AND rating='2'"; 
}   
elseif($_POST['value'] == '3') { 
    // query to get all 3 star ratings
    $query = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE genre='action' AND rating='3'"; 
    }   
elseif($_POST['value'] == '4') { 
    // query to get all 4 star ratings
    $query = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE genre='action' AND rating='4'"; 
    }   
elseif($_POST['value'] == '5') { 
    // query to get all 5 star ratings
    $query = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE genre='action' AND rating='5'"; 
} 

WHILE($board = mysql_fetch_array($result)):
$title = $board['title'];
$studio = $board['studio'];
$language = $board['language'];
$certification = $board['certification'];

echo '
Title : '.$title.'<br />
Studio : '.$studio.'<br />
Language : '.$language.'<br />
Certification : '.$certification.'<br />
;
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: There are multiple links over to the right under "Related" where I found many Q&A's that will help you solve this, one of which being => http://stackoverflow.com/q/15385085/ --- You need to use a loop which isn't included/shown in your question.

Comment: You should also remove the space in `$ comments`

Comment: Thanks but that looks very different from what I need.

Comment: So, what problems are you having with what you posted (as an edit)?

Comment: The page refreshes but the query doesn't run, the content of the query is not displayed.

Comment: I take it that both your bodies of code are inside the same file, by the looks of `action=""`. If so, you will need to wrap your entire PHP with `if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){...}`

Comment: I posted an answer below for you to try. I've tested it myself so it should work for you also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way, assuming you're already connected and have selected DB and that you're using your entire code inside the same file, since you are using `action=""`; this denotes executing as "self".

You also are not executing `mysql_query()` which I have added below.

Be sure to change `xxx` below with your DB credentials and `your_db` to your database's name.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$Host = "xxx";
$User = "xxx";
$Password = "xxx";

$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('your_db', $Link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use that DB : ' . mysql_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

if($_POST['value'] == '1') { 
    // query to get all 1 star ratings
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM films WHERE genre='action' AND rating='1'"); 
} 
elseif($_POST['value'] == '2') { 
    // query to get all 2 star ratings
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM films WHERE genre='action' AND rating='2'"); 
}   
elseif($_POST['value'] == '3') { 
    // query to get all 3 star ratings
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM films WHERE genre='action' AND rating='3'"); 
    }   
elseif($_POST['value'] == '4') { 
    // query to get all 4 star ratings
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM films WHERE genre='action' AND rating='4'"); 
    }   
elseif($_POST['value'] == '5') { 
    // query to get all 5 star ratings
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM films WHERE genre='action' AND rating='5'"); 
}

WHILE($board = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$title = $board['title'];
$studio = $board['studio'];
$language = $board['language'];
$certification = $board['certification'];

echo '
Title : '.$title.'<br />
Studio : '.$studio.'<br />
Language : '.$language.'<br />
Certification : '.$certification.'<br />';
}
} // brace for if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
?>

</div>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="genericForm">
<fieldset>
<p>Filter Rating</p>
<select name="value">
<option value="1">One Star</option>
<option value="2">Two Stars</option>
<option value="3">Three Stars</option>
<option value="4">Four Stars</option>
<option value="5">Five Stars</option>
</select>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"><br  />
</form>
```

---

**Note:**
This `enctype="multipart/form-data"` isn't required if it's not going to be used to upload files.

Comment: Thank you. That almost did the trick. It outputs one result e.g. if I have a movie rated 5 stars three times, If I select 5 and click submit it only displays the last 5 star rated comment.

Comment: You're welcome. @raybarone So, you want to display more than one record that matches each criteria, is that it?

Comment: Yes I have dozens of results so if I select 4 stars I should see ten four star reviews. I tried to add square braces to store the values as arrays but that didn't work.

Comment: I re-tested my answer (as shown above) and I've copied the same data from row 1 to row 3 (I have 3 records in there) and it did show me row 1 and 3 but not row 2. Do you have matching data in both rows (more rows and one) of your search criteria? @raybarone

Comment: No. All the comments are posted by the same user but the comments and times are different.

Comment: You will need to modify your query/queries then to match what you want to match. If you remove the `genre='action' AND` in `WHERE genre='action' AND rating='1'` and just do `WHERE rating='1'` am sure you will get more results if you have data in rows where rating equals `1`. @raybarone It all boils down to how you set up your query. That I can't control. You will need to do that.

Comment: You may also need to use `ORDER BY column_name GROUP BY column_name` ---- `column_name` being the column of your choice, yet they both need to be the same to get better results. @raybarone

Comment: Plus, if you don't have matching data for both columns you're fetching, it's because of the `AND`. Using `AND` is saying match THIS **"and"** THAT. If one fails, then it won't show you all the ones you're hoping to show. You may need to use `OR`. I.e.: `WHERE genre='action' OR rating='1'` @raybarone that way if one criteria matches and one fails, you will still get results.

Comment: The query executes in phpmyadmin and displays several results e.g. SELECT * FROM films WHERE genre='action' AND rating='1' gives 2 results. I'm sure it's something simple! I'll keep trying.

Comment: Another thing you can try is removing the quotes around the numbers `AND rating='1'` and do `AND rating=1` if your column is an `INT` that could be it. @raybarone

Comment: That didn't work either and the ratings column is an INT. It should work!

Comment: It was the position of a brace! Got someone else to look at it. Unbelievable. Hate php. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken this is what you want? you just need to loop through the row in the tables and fetch it.

```
<div class="form">

<?php

$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
$Query = "select * from books where product = 'hannibal' AND book = '1'";

$result = mysql_query($Query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $subject = $row['subject'];
    $username = $row['username']; 
    $date = $row['date'];
    $comments = $row['comments'];
    ?>
     <h1>Subject : <?php echo $subject;?>
     Posted by <?php echo $username;?> on <?php echo $date;?></h1><br />
      <?php echo $comments;?>'; <br />
<?php
}
?>

</div>
```

Comment: This line `<?php echo $comments;?><br />';` should be changed to `<?php echo $comments;?><br />` the `';` will show up in the echo.

Comment: No. I have updated the HTML and php. It should make more sense. Sorry for the confusion.